# Code for booking site

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've a table with some records like this

```
date         price
01/02/2000   20  
02/02/2000   20 
03/02/2000   20
```

the user will choose on my site the date of check-in and out. For example:

```
check-in: 01/02
check-out: 02/02
```

I' can i do a function that count the day from 01/02 to 02/02, and sum the price of the 2 days?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Show us some of your code!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows no research effort.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple `SQL` to calculate the count and sum of the fields between your dates:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_dates, SUM(price) AS total_price
FROM your_table
WHERE date >= '01/02/2000'
AND date <= '02/02/2000'
```

Comment: thanks a lot..and if i'd like to show on my website the sum (in this case 40) what's the function?

Comment: ...there isn't one. This is just SQL; you need to use a database driver ([like `PDO`](http://us3.php.net/pdo_mysql)) to actually use the results.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is not enough infromation what you realy want to get. But my best gues:

```
SELECT SUM(Price), Count(*) as count_day
Where date>check-in and date<check-out
```